# How to reduce TTFB for webpage using heroku free service

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, pagespeed-insights, time-to-first-byte

I recently uploaded a website to heroku (using their free service). The website is built using node.js and express. According to google I had a page speed score of 99 and 100 for mobile and desktop respectively. The following day I made some basic changes to the html and  css, and after pushing to heroku again the TTFB is now extremely slow. The app was out of hibernation mode when I did the speed tests. Is this issue with Heroku's servers or should I look for another way to solve it? I don't know how changing the html and css would cause TTFB issues. Is this a common issue with Heroku?

Update: After pushing changes to heroku a second time I had no problems. Seems to have been a glitch with heroku's server.

Answer (score 0):

TTFB is the time that the server takes to show the first byte of content. This audit fails when the browser waits more than 600ms for the server to respond to the main document request.

So, I don't know much about Heroku but if it is a free service, the response time must be much slower than the payment plans.